# Puppet: Pass facter value to class (sensu puppet module)

Tags: puppet, facter, sensu

Trying to set a custom subscription to get remediator.rb working in the sensu module in puppet.

```
class sensuJenkinsMasterClient {
  class { 'sensu': 
     purge_config       => true,
     rabbitmq_password  => '',
     rabbitmq_host      => 'sensu-master',
     #Need fqdn for remediator to work
     subscriptions      => ['sensu-default', 'centosJenkinsMaster', '"${::fqdn}'], 
     use_embedded_ruby  => true, #set under /etc/default/sensu
  }
}
```

Comment: You put that in single quotes which prevents variable expansion. Have you tried `"${::fqdn}"`?

Comment: Agreed, you have some strange quoting going on.  Remove the single quotes around the double quotes around fqdn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single quotes prevent variables from getting expanded, so it should be like this:

```
     subscriptions      => [ 'sensu-default', 'centosJenkinsMaster', $::fqdn, ],
```

I'd recommend you to use `puppet-lint`.
In that case it would have told you:

```
ERROR: single quoted string containing a variable found on line X
```